# Insertion on MySql Table Fails

Tags: python, mysql, crud, web2py, pydal

Guys I am building an application with web2py and I need to store and query some information from my MySql datababase. I am trying to insert a row in the table **search_term**. I am following strictly the web2Py DAL and pyDAL documentations.

```
#my table definition

CREATE TABLE search_term (
 term_id  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 term varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 lang varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 since_date date DEFAULT NULL,
 until_date date DEFAULT NULL,
 quantity int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (term_id)
 );


#in db.py
db = DAL('mysql://myUser:myPassWord@localhost/myDB')

search_term_table = db.define_table('search_term',
            Field('term_id', 'integer'),
            Field('term', 'string', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
            Field('lang', 'string', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
            Field('quantity', 'integer', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
            Field('since_date', 'date', requires=[IS_DATETIME()]),
            Field('until_date', 'date', requires=[IS_DATETIME()]))

#in controller
result = search_term_table.insert(term = "sample", lang = 'en', quantity = 300)
```

When I am debugging, everything seems to occur well, but when I execute the select * from search_table in MySQL Workbench, to verify if the data was stored, the table is still empty. Am I doing something wrong? Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: After insert, are you committing your changes using something like:

db.commit(). Just curious.

Comment: Yeah. I am using the db.commit. I already reviewed my code, my db connection is working but I can't insert successfully my data.

Comment: Note that it's `db.commit()`, not `db.commit` (notice the parens).

Comment: Owwww. Thanks. Yeah, my mistake was not put (). Now it works. Thanks both of you! I really appreciate.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers how did you get to know that he missed ( ) :O

Comment: @NoorAliJafri I did not "know" (else I would have posted this as an answer), I only thought it _might_ be the case (first because he wrote " I am using the db.commit" (without parens), then because it's a very common mistake and the symptom did match the problem description).

Comment: Awesome, good to know the thought process.

Comment: If the code in question is in a web2py controller, then it is running in response to an HTTP request, and therefore `db.commit()` is not necessary, as the framework calls it automatically at the end of HTTP request handling. Is the code really in a controller, or in a module? Or are you running the code via the web2py shell?

Comment: Also, the `term_id` field definition should be `Field('term_id', 'id')` so web2py knows that is the `id` field.

Comment: @Anthony the code is in a module where I make the inserts and updates, deletes, and so on. }Thanks for Field('term_id', 'id') tip, I didnt realize that was needed to configure in that way. Thanks